# sudo wipe command in terminal error

Tags: fdisk

I did the command

```
sudo wipe /dev/sdb
```

where `/dev/sdb` is my 1TB HDD and I got a "command not found" message. How would I be able to prepare the drive for new OS? Wipe it, I mean.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will wipe all partitions, MBR, and data.  Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/sdx bs=1M
```

**Note**: You need to replace x with the device name you want to overwrite.  Also make sure that you really want to do this, because it might not be reversible.  So make sure that you have a backup of anything that you want off the drive before attempting this.

Comment: this worked the second time around. got it.

Answer (score 0):

Try `Gparted Partition Editor` from *System-->Administration* to format your external HDD.Please note that,to format a partition it must be **unmounted**.

Answer (score 0):

Actually wipe is not pre-installed application and you have to install it manually.

open your terminal and type as

```
sudo apt-get install wipe
```

then run the command again.

Comment: I did just that thank you, I got fatal error: could not lstat: no such file or directory. Could you help again

Comment: are you mentioning the proper command ? could you place the log here ?

Comment: I have just removed the drive and dealt wit it differently. I must study ubuntu a little more. thanks